# How get CLASS from UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift

I have UIViewController and how I can to convert UIViewController to Class.swift. Class is initialized...

```
MainController.staticInstance.viewControllers?[1] as! Destination
```

MainController is class which extending UITabBarController. I want to get child controller from UITabBar and convert it to Class which parent.

Clearly example:

```
class MainController: UITabBarController {
override func viewDidLoad() {
  (self.viewControllers?[1] as! Destination).itsMyFunction();
 }
}
```

MAXIMUM DETAIL:

1 class

```
class First: UIViewController {
 func itsMyFunction() {
  print("Hello world!")
 }
}
```

this is Class I attach to class in STORYBOARD!

2 class

```
class MainController: UITabBarController {
     func override viewDidLoad() {
       // Here I set index UITabBar ITEM which attach to MAIN UiTabBarController
       self.selectedIndex = 0
       // NOW I want to get INSTANCE CLASS First
       (self.viewControllers?[1] as! First).itsMyFunction();
     }
}
```

Comment: What are you asking? Is the posted code generating an error, if so what is the error?

Comment: MainController is class which extending UITabBarController. I want to get child controller from UITabBar and convert it to Class which parent.

Comment: What you meant by **convert it to Class which parent** ??

Comment: 1. I have UITabBarController and it have four tabBarItem. 2. I want to access the first controller that is tied to a class in a storyboard.

Comment: Aren't you already doing it by `as! Destination`? Isn't your `Destination` is the `Class` you are talking about?

Comment: I updated example.

Comment: You still haven't told us why your code doesn't work. What is happening when you do `as! First` or `as! Destination` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please follow this setup example?

```
class TabBarViewController: UITabBarController {

let firstVC = First()
let secondVC = SecondViewController()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    firstVC.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(tabBarSystemItem: .search, tag: 0)
    secondVC.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(tabBarSystemItem: .more, tag: 1)

    let tabBarList = [firstVC, secondVC]

    viewControllers = tabBarList

    if let destination = viewControllers?.first as? First {
      destination.itsMyFunction()
    }
  }
}
```

It seems that you fail to get the `Class` instance of the `controller` because your `viewControllers` array is empty based on the code that you posted. Let me know if it worked.

Answer (score 0):

That way you get a crash if the type is something different. Try to avoid using ! whenever you can.
Use a weak cast and evaluate the unwrapped type if its yours.

```
if let destination = destMainController.staticInstance.viewControllers?.first as? Destination {
     destination.itsMyFunction()
}
```

Comment: It's don't want convert controller to Class Instance

Comment: Well then you need to describe your question more clearly.

Comment: I added maximum detail in top

Comment: I can't do it??

Comment: You mean the name of the class? classForCoder?